# Convert excel column to "Date" versus general or custom

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a very simple code that intakes an xlsm file and filters on certain columns and then fills in template sheet with those same columns.

Problem is that the template sheet columns that have dates or when converted to datetime, astype or other methods of converting to dates, they all end up being either as a "General" or "Custom" format in excel document when saved. I need them to be in "Date" format because the file is used to feed in to another algorithm that doesn't pick up the columns if they are not in a 'date' format.

Tried astype() and datetype

```py
input = 'input_file.xlsm'
current_roster = pd.read_excel(input, 'Roster', header = 0)

roster_columns = ['Name', 'Effective_Date']

roster_df = current_roster[roster_columns]


path = 'Output_File.xlsx'
book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

roster_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Roster', index =False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Ideally I would like to be able to open the excel file and see the Effective_Date column be formatted as "Date"

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: in a hacky way, before converting to excel you could add a couple of columns, one that enumerates the `Effective_Date` cells as a string, and the other that builds a `DATE` formula out of that, something like: `roster_df['cell'] = "A%s" % i` (where `i` is in a range) and then `roster_df['formula'] = roster_df['cell'].apply(lambda x: "=DATE(%s)" % x)` or something like that then `to_excel`. Maybe that would work?

Comment: hyu~ nice hack.. like +1